# Does data.table export a method for testing its .internal.selfref sentinel? If not, how to test this sentinel?

Tags: r, data.table, warnings

I'm asking because I'm trying to identify the root cause(s) for the warnings about "Invalid .internal.selfref detected and fixed" that I have triggered on five occasions while developing code using `data.table`.  It seems pretty clear that, somewhere along the line, my code performs an operation on a `data.table` which causes it to be copied -- at least under some conditions. It's a *long* path to the warning, and my code-inspection hasn't revealed any likely suspects. Until I can localise the defect, I can't produce an MRE -- nor can I be confident of the integrity of the data.tables produced by my code.

A reasonably-efficient way to localise what I'm tentatively labelling an "inadvertent copy defect" would be to pepper-pot my code with stopifnot() invocations.  But!  I can't figure out how to write a valid.internal.selfref() method.

[Section 5.13 of Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#External-pointers-and-weak-references) tells me that this method can't be written in R.  I'm pretty sure there'll be a C-language internal method of data.table which guards the "Invalid .internal.selfref detected and fixed" warning.

[Warning: 'Invalid .internal.selfref detected' when adding a column to a data.table returned from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20687235/warning-invalid-internal-selfref-detected-when-adding-a-column-to-a-data-tab) has a very nice explanation of `.internal.selfref`, but fails to reveal (at least in my reading) how a user of `data.table` could test this sentinel.

Comment: It's unlikely such a function would be exported since `.internal.selfref` is supposed to be an implementation detail. Without knowing more details, liberal use of `copy()` in situations where this warning arises can be seen as a good thing.

Comment: Indeed `copy()` can be helpful, if you're not terribly concerned about the integrity of the attributes (and the data!) in your `data.table`.  However I'm developing a package that will perform stochastic experimentation, so it's really important that the experimental data be reliably preserved -- along with the values of secondary factors (which I'm storing in object-level attributes).   I can read corrupted `data.tables` using `load()`, copy them using `data.table::copy()`, and `save()` them again -- that'll clear the copy-detection sentinel but won't repair any corrupted data or  attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at `data.table` source code, this warning seems to be triggered [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/2f675318268ab483da16e4ad49e5d66c9ef7d3b4/R/data.table.R#L1174).

This means you could use the internal `data.table:::selfrefok` function:

```r
library(data.table)

data.table:::selfrefok(data.table(x=1))
#> [1] 1
data.table:::selfrefok(data.frame(x=1))
#> [1] 0
```

Comment: Thanks!!  I'm now hot on the trail of the (until-now) elusive DT operation in my code that corrupts a `data.table`.  `stopifnot(data.table:::selfrefok(dt)==1)` is my new friend ;-)

Comment: I have isolated and repaired a couple of defects.  Subclassing a DT using `class(DT) <-` had corrupted my DT, and it was also corrupted by `DT <- dplyr::bind_rows(DT,row)`.  The former is sort-of-obviously hazardous after thinking through the implications of the .internal.selfref warning message.  The latter is a surprising hazard, given that dplyr is "One of the core packages of the tidyverse in the R programming language".

Comment: glad `selfrefok` helped to detect some issues ;-) . `dplyr::bind_rows` [seems to be a known one](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3274)